# Multiplying all values of an array using an enhanced loop? Java

Tags: java, arrays

The title pretty much covers it. For some reason this problem is escaping me and I can't find the logical answer to this.

EDIT:

Say I have

```
int[] values = (2,5,3,2,1,4,6,3,2,1,5,3)
```

I want to get the product of multiplying all these elements. My textbook asks to do this with an enhanced for loop.

```
for (int element : values)
{
NO CLUE WHAT TO PUT HERE
}
```

My first guess, however, was that it couldn't be done with an enhanced for loop.

Is my textbook just trying to trick me to teach me some sort of lesson?

Comment: The standard response: What have you got so far?

Comment: How do you think someone can help you without seeing your code?

Comment: No, the title didn't cover it.

Comment: The title is ambiguous. Multiplying each value by some factor or multiplying all values together?

Comment: If you don't even know how to use an accumulator variable you need to go back to the basics son.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with enhanced for loop. 
Assume you have an array: (*I updated the answer after the OP has updated the question, the update is below*).

`int[] a = {1,2,3};`

When you do:

```
for(int num : a) {
  num = num*something;
}
```

You are actually multiplying *another variable* (the array won't be affected)..

`num` in the above example is only *a copy of an array element*. So actually you are modifying a local variable, not the array itself.

Read **[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)** and you'll see that the value in the array is **copied into a local variable**, and this local variable is used. So this multiplication will not affect the original values of the arrays.

---

*OP UPDATE*:

If you want to multiply elements and get the result, you **can**. Your text book is not trying to trick you. It doesn't ask you to *change* the values. But to use them in order to do some calculations:

```
int[] values = {2,5,3,2,1,4,6,3,2,1,5,3};
int result=1;
for(int value : values) {
    result *= value;
} 
System.out.println("The result: " + result); //Will print the result of 2*5*3*2*...
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can easily be done with an enhanced for loop:**

```
int result = 1;
for (int element : values)
{
    result *= element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done, you will have to use old-style array addressing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i] * 2;
}
```

Comment: Or a foreach, since he does not need to over ride the original values.

Comment: Yeah, an edit to the question has made my response incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
for (int element : values)
{

    values[index] = element + someVariable;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.